# set breakpoint in the process started by other process

Tags: c, gdb

I am faced with a situation wherein I have process X executing a 
a command ( say `/bin/ls` ). as soon as the process X executes the command ls 
I want to put a breakpoint in a function in `ls`.

Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Not sure, but I would read this: http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Forks.html

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution may be to wrap the binary in question (that is called by process X) in a small shell script that starts the process in a debug session and applies pre-configured breakpoints as well.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways to do it.

1. Simplest is to `set follow-fork-mode child` whenever new new client process is created GDB will debug the child. However with this mode you will not be able to debug the parent process any more.
2. In the child process (`ls` mentioned above) add some code to wait for a signal say SIGCONT at the very beginning. Whenever child process is created attach GDB (new GDB instance) to it with its PID of child process, issue the singnal SIGCONT to continue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `catch exec` [[1](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Catchpoints.html)] to stop on `exec` calls:

```
(gdb) catch exec
Catchpoint 1 (exec)
(gdb) r
Starting program: /tmp/a.out
process 7544 is executing new program: /bin/ls

Catchpoint 1 (exec'd /bin/ls), 0x00007ffff7ddfaf0 in _start () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

Then you can do whatever you want with the new process. See also the [link in the comment](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Forks.html) by *dbrank0* for various fork-related options.